# Asynchronous loading of views/handling promises in AngularJS views with jq-plot

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, jqplot

I have a controller for a jq-plot as below:

```
app.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', 'Model1', 'Model2', function($scope, Model1, Model2) {
   var model1 = new Model1();
   model1.firstAsyncMethod(function() {
      var model2 = new Model2();
      model2.secondAsyncMethod(function() {
        $scope.data = [ [1,6.5],[2,6.5],[3,7],[4,8],[5,7.5],[6,7],[7,6.8],[8,7],[9,7.2],[10,7],[11,6.8],[12,7] ];
      })
   });
}]);
```

As you can see , I'm first calling the `firstAsyncMethod()` and passes a callback to it. This call back makes another async call to `secondAsyncMethod()`. It's only at the end when this `secondAsyncMethod()` resolves my `$scope.data` becomes available.

In the meantime, my view for this controller looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="chartCtrl">
    <div ui-jq="plot" ui-options="
          [
            { data: {{data}}}
          ]
        ">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is when `ui-options` tries to load `data` on page load, the controller has not returned `data` yet. This throws parse errors in angularJS.

I tried to define the chart options in the controller after the second async method fully resolved but I still keep getting errors. How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Where do `model1` and `model2` come from?

Comment: @NexusDuck They are factories. Sorry I forgot to show their constructors. I have added them and updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally managed to find a simpler solution. All you need to do is add `ui-refresh` directive to the view:

```
<div ng-controller="chartCtrl">
<div ui-jq="plot" ui-refresh="data" ui-options="
      [
        { data: {{data}}}
      ]
    ">
</div>
```

In the controller you have to define `data` to some default value outside of the async calls to stop throwing the error:

```
app.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', 'Model1', 'Model2', function($scope, Model1, Model2) {
    $scope.data = [[0,0]];
       var model1 = new Model1();
       model1.firstAsyncMethod(function() {
          var model2 = new Model2();
          model2.secondAsyncMethod(function() {
            $scope.data = [ [1,6.5],[2,6.5],[3,7],[4,8],[5,7.5],[6,7],[7,6.8],[8,7],[9,7.2],[10,7],[11,6.8],[12,7] ];
          })
       });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), this will make (usually asynchronously fetched) data available in your controller when it loads. It's available both in `ngRoute` and `ui-router`, you'll also have to wrap these callbacks in a promise using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Add this to the route definition for `chartCtrl`:

```
resolve: {
  modelData: function($q, Model1, Model2) {
    //use $q to wrap asynchronous callbacks in promises
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var model1 = new Model1();
    model1.firstAsyncMethod(function() {
      var model2 = new Model2();
      model2.secondAsyncMethod(function() {
        var data = [ [1,6.5],[2,6.5],[3,7],[4,8],[5,7.5],[6,7],[7,6.8],[8,7],[9,7.2],[10,7],[11,6.8],[12,7] ];
        deferred.resolve(data);
      });
   });
   return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

You can then inject `modelData` in your controller:

```
app.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', 'modelData', function($scope, modelData) {
  $scope.data = modelData;
}]);
```